# Latest Array and previous array values compare

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, html

I am new to javascript and angular. Now Here this might be a duplicate question, But I am facing issue in this ,

So, I have two arrays of objects:

```
$scope.previous = [{name: 'A', Value: 'B'}, {name: 'ABC', value: 'PQR'}];
```

and I have a new updated array:

```
$scope.updated = [{name: 'A', value:'C'}, {name: 'K', value: 'S'}, {name: 'ABC', value: 'PQR'}]
```

Now Updated is nothing but after some operations previous becomes like this.

NOw here, I want to compare this new with previous.

SO that If an object is not present in previous and is in updated then it should it add it in the diff array. Again If an object is same in the two arrays then it should not get added in the new array, and If an object is present in the updated array but not in the previous array then it should not get added in the diff array. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var previous = [{name: 'A', Value: 'B'}, {name: 'ABC', value: 'PQR'}];
var updated = [{name: 'A', value:'C'}, {name: 'K', value: 'S'}, {name: 'ABC', value: 'PQR'}]

function comparer(otherArray){
  return function(current){
    return otherArray.filter(function(other){
      return other.value == current.value && other.display == current.display
    }).length == 0;
  }
}
var onlyInA = previous.filter(comparer(updated));
var onlyInB = updated.filter(comparer(previous));

console.log(onlyInA);
console.log(onlyInB);

difference = previous.filter(function(x) { return updated.indexOf(x) < 0 })

console.log(difference);
```

```js
var previous = [{name: 'A', Value: 'B'}, {name: 'ABC', value: 'PQR'}];
var updated = [{name: 'A', value:'C'}, {name: 'K', value: 'S'}, {name: 'ABC', value: 'PQR'}]

var presentInArray = _.intersectionWith(previous, updated, _.isEqual);
console.log(presentInArray) //present in array
var differenceInArray = _.differenceWith(previous, updated, _.isEqual);
console.log(differenceInArray);//difference in array
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to get difference between two array of object

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually I am not allow to use external libraries. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple, no need for adding extra library solution. I am considering name to be unique in each object, it could be different in you case.

```js
 

      const prev = [{name: 'A', value: 'C'}, {name: 'ABC', value: 'PQR'},{name: 'sss', value: 'sss'} ];
    const latest = [{name: 'AX', value:'CX'}, {name: 'K', value: 'S'}, {name: 'ABC', value: 'PQR'}];
      const whatDoesNotInclude = [];
const inPrevNotInLatest = [];
    
    const searchByname = (nameKey, myArray) => {
        for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            if (myArray[i].name === nameKey) {
                return myArray[i];
            }
        }
    }
    
    latest.forEach(l =>{
      if (searchByname(l.name, prev)) {   
      }else {
        whatDoesNotInclude.push(l);
      }
    });

 prev.forEach(l =>{
      if (searchByname(l.name, latest)) {   
      }else {
        inPrevNotInLatest.push(l);
      }
    });
    
    console.log(whatDoesNotInclude);
console.log(inPrevNotInLatest);
```

Comment: Here , if I want to have another array where the objects that are not in the updated array but are in the previous array ?

Comment: @ganesh I have updated the code now you should get both ways

Comment: @ganesh is the updated code satisfies your need? Then mark it as answer if done.